# Subset a javascript object literal by matching an array of values

Tags: javascript, filter

I need to subset an object literal `myData` with those elements that belong to `group` B **and** with `year` matching those found in `group` A:

```
var myData = [{"year":1,"group":"A","value":0.1},
 {"year":2,"group":"A","value":0.2},
 {"year":3,"group":"A","value":0.2},
 {"year":4,"group":"A","value":0.1},
 {"year":5,"group":"A","value":0.1},
 {"year":1,"group":"B","value":0.1},
 {"year":2,"group":"B","value":0.2},
 {"year":3,"group":"B","value":0.2},
 {"year":4,"group":"B","value":0.2},
 {"year":5,"group":"B","value":0.9},
 {"year":6,"group":"B","value":0.1}] ;
```

I can use `.filter()` to get the desired output:

```
mySubset = myData.filter((d) => {return d.group == "B" && d.year < 6;});
```

resulting in:

```
[{"year":1,"group":"B","value":0.1},
  {"year":2,"group":"B","value":0.2},
  {"year":3,"group":"B","value":0.2},
  {"year":4,"group":"B","value":0.2},
  {"year":5,"group":"B","value":0.9}];
```

But this is not ideal. I want a generic, all-purpose solution that does not depend on "manually" inputting the max value (6). Also, `year` may not be a sequence (e.g. `[2, 1, 4, 5]`).

Essentially, the hurdle is in the second part of the condtion (`d.year < 6`). I would need something that would match the values found in:

```
let x = []

for(i = 0; i < myData.filter((d) => {return d.group == "A";}).length; i++){
    x.push(myData[i].year);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: maybe make your subset a function that takes a `year` as an argument and returns your filtered array using the passed year argument

Comment: const getSubset = year => myData.filter(d => d.group == "B" && d.year < year)

Then you can loop over your Array of years and on each iteration - pass the year to the `getSubset` function

Comment: @FrancisLeigh Seems like a good solution to me. You should add this as an answer, and in general, avoid providing answers in the comments

Comment: True, thanks will sort that

Comment: @FrancisLeigh Although, if you are going to make a function, the `group` should also be a parameter

Comment: @FrancisLeigh Thanks for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're halfway there; now that you have an array of all the years in group "A", you just need to check if the year in group "B" is in that array. You can use `.includes()` for this.

```
mySubset = myData.filter((d) => {return d.group == "B" && x.includes(d.year);});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a `Set` which contains all the years of group `A`, than  can filter out element from the array, (if the set has Year present and the group is B than add it to the result) :

```js
var myData = [{"year":1,"group":"A","value":0.1}, {"year":2,"group":"A","value":0.2}, {"year":3,"group":"A","value":0.2}, {"year":4,"group":"A","value":0.1}, {"year":5,"group":"A","value":0.1}, {"year":1,"group":"B","value":0.1}, {"year":2,"group":"B","value":0.2}, {"year":3,"group":"B","value":0.2}, {"year":4,"group":"B","value":0.2}, {"year":5,"group":"B","value":0.9}, {"year":6,"group":"B","value":0.1}];

let set = new Set(myData.filter(e=>e.group =="A").map(e=>e.year));

let result = myData.filter(e=> e.group =="B" && set.has(e.year));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

By making a `getSubset()` Function you are able to pass the desired group and year as arguments (thanks @mhodges)

I also filter out any potentially empty arrays inside your yearGroups array incase the year does not match anything

```js
let myData = [
 {"year":1,"group":"A","value":0.1},
 {"year":2,"group":"A","value":0.2},
 {"year":3,"group":"A","value":0.2},
 {"year":4,"group":"A","value":0.1},
 {"year":5,"group":"A","value":0.1},
 {"year":1,"group":"B","value":0.1},
 {"year":2,"group":"B","value":0.2},
 {"year":3,"group":"B","value":0.2},
 {"year":4,"group":"B","value":0.2},
 {"year":5,"group":"B","value":0.9},
 {"year":6,"group":"B","value":0.1}
]


let getSubsets = (group = 'B', year = 6) => myData.filter(d => d.group == group && d.year < year)

console.log(getSubsets())

console.log(getSubsets('A', 4))

let yearGroups = [1,2,3,4,5].map(y => getSubsets('B', y)).filter(a => !!a.length)

console.log(yearGroups)
```

Comment: I will go with @AsherMaximum but this is a cool solution too. thnx